# analytics report API in PHP : (403) Insufficient Permission

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

here is my code.

```
<?php

session_start();
include_once "templates/base.php";

set_include_path("../src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Books.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';

$client_id = '...'; //Client ID
$service_account_name = '...'; //Email Address 
$key_file_location = 'key.p12'; //key.p12

echo pageHeader("Service Account Access");
if ($client_id == '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>'
    || !strlen($service_account_name)
    || !strlen($key_file_location)) {
  echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();
}

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
//$service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),
    $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

$analytics_id   = 'ga:88243354';
$lastWeek       = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week'));
$today          = date('Y-m-d');
try {
    $results = $service->data_ga->get($analytics_id,
                        $lastWeek,
                        $today,'ga:sessions');
    echo '<b>Number of visits this week:</b> ';
    echo $result;
    echo $results['totalsForAllResults']['ga:ssessions'];
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'There was an error : - ' . $e->getMessage();
}

echo pageFooter(__FILE__);
```

I receive the error message

> Error (403) Insufficient Permission.

Of course, I need turn on the Analytics API at my development console.
and add the client email to google profile user.

I need a help ;-;

Comment: Did you change the line `if ($client_id == '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>'` ?

Comment: @Rapter That part is just verifying whether I change the client_id above, it has not much meaning... I receive the 403 error which mean, I can receive the token..

Comment: It works automatically,,,,, just need a time to verifying my email account to analytics server.